# SQL generated by jOOQ for nested select doesn't work in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, jooq

For a classical ranking problem (sum of best 3 results per player) I came up with the following sub-query using the **jOOQ DSL** and **Scala** (to be embedded as **select** value and joined in a more complex query):

```
val tr1 = TOUR_RESULT.as("tr1")
val tr2 = TOUR_RESULT.as("tr2")
val inner:Table[Record1[java.lang.Integer]] = DSL.select(count().as("count")).from(tr2).where(tr1.PLAYER_ID.eq(tr2.PLAYER_ID).and(tr1.NSP_SCORE.le(tr2.NSP_SCORE))).asTable("tr3") 
val result = sql.select(tr1.PLAYER_ID,tr1.NSP_SCORE.sum().as("score"))
    .from(tr1)
    .where(inline(3).gt(sql.selectQuery(inner)))
    .groupBy(tr1.PLAYER_ID)
    .orderBy(2)
    .execute()
```

My problem currently (using MariaDB 10 and jOOQ 3.9) is to make this generated query work with MySQL at all and to sort by 'Score' (Column 2) descending.
I'm confident I could rewrite the whole statement using the raw SQL statement and casting the result (therefore bypassing the jOOQ API). However I'd like to stay clean with the compiler and the jOOQ API as my shepherd as long as possible. So maybe there is a solution that will still be readable in the future if I ever have to touch this query again.

The schema and generated SQL illustrating the case can be found under
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f614f/3 with the offending lines/statements in comments.

```
    create table TOUR_RESULT (
      player_id int,
      nsp_score int
    );

    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (1,4);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (1,14);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (1,24);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (1,34);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (1,44);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (2,3);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (2,13);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (2,23);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (2,33);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (2,43);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (3,3);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (3,13);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (4,130);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,2);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,7);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,7);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,7);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,5);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,7);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,10);
    insert into TOUR_RESULT values (5,12);

    SELECT `tr1`.`player_id`, sum(`tr1`.`nsp_score`) AS `score`
      FROM `tour_result` AS `tr1`
      WHERE 3 >=
    --    (SELECT `tr3`.`count`
    --     FROM
     (SELECT count(*) AS `count`
       FROM `tour_result` AS `tr2`
       WHERE (`tr1`.`player_id` = `tr2`.`player_id`
           AND `tr1`.`nsp_score` <= `tr2`.`nsp_score`)) 
    --               AS `tr3`)
    GROUP BY `tr1`.`player_id`
    ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

The error when uncommenting the lines is

```
    Unknown column 'tr1.player_id' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: "best 3 results" for a player appear to be the three lowest nsp_score values. what happens when there are duplicate nsp_score values for a player, for example, what should the result be when nsp_scores for a player are `(2),(7),(7),(7),(7),(10),(12)` ?  (i.e. let's make sure the query we're coming up with satisfies the specification...)

Comment: Good catch. I've updated the scenario. The rabbit holes of seemingly trivial tasks is always amazing ...

Comment: `ORDER BY 2 DESC` corresponds to `DSL.inline(2).desc()` in jOOQ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, MariaDB and MySQL don't allow for referencing columns "two levels up" in your correlated subqueries. But if you have MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0, you can use [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) for the job:

#### SQL Version

```sql
SELECT tr1.player_id, SUM(nsp_score) AS score
FROM (
  SELECT 
    tr2.player_id, 
    tr2.nsp_score, 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY tr2.player_id ORDER BY tr2.nsp_score DESC) rn
  FROM tour_result AS tr2
) AS tr1
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY tr1.player_id;
```

Filtering by `ROW_NUMBER()` will pick exactly 3 winning rows among the scores. If you want to have 3 or more rows, if they're tied (`WITH TIES` semantics), you can use `RANK()`. [I've also blogged about this topic in the past](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/).

#### jOOQ Version

This translates to the following jOOQ query:

```scala
val tr1 = TOUR_RESULT.as("tr1")
val tr2 = TOUR_RESULT.as("tr2")
val result = sql
    .select(tr1.PLAYER_ID, sum(tr1.NSP_SCORE).as("score"))
    .from(table(
       select(
         tr2.PLAYER_ID,
         tr2.NSP_SCORE,
         rowNumber().over(
           partitionBy(tr2.PLAYER_ID)
          .orderBy(tr2.NSP_SCORE.desc())).as("rn"))
      .from(tr2)
    ).as(tr1))
    .where(field(name("rn")).le(inline(3)))
    .groupBy(tr1.PLAYER_ID)
    .fetch()
```

The above is assuming an import of

```scala
import org.jooq.impl.DSL._
```